# ELASTIC SEARCH - SEARCH IN LOGS

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'd like to perform a search in log file to find out if only accepted values are used

"Field1" : "A"
"Field2" : "B"
"Field3" : "D"

I tried with

*GET compteas_stat_index_1/_search*

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [{"match": {"Field1": "A"}},
                   {"match": {"Field2":"B"}},
                   {"match":{"Field3":"C"}}]
    }
  }
}
```

But I can't get the expected result when having C,B,C, it doesn't come in result window,

thx for any help
best regards

Comment: You have mentioned ABC in the query and ABD in the question. Which one do you want to avoid? Do you want to avoid this specific combo : `A AND B AND C` ?

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {"match": {"Field1": "A"}},
            {"match": {"Field2": "B"}},
            {"match": {"Field3": "C"}}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Markusk, it does the job !  waht if i want "must not" ((A and B and C) or (E and F and G)) here what i have with you help for must not ((A and B and C))GET  file_index_1/_search
{    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must_not" : {
                      "bool": {
                            "must": [{"match": {"field1": "A"}},
                                     {"match": {"field2":"B"}},
                                     {"match":{"field3":"C"}}]
                      }
            }              
          }                        
      } 
}        Greeetings

Comment: @sysley If you are happy with the answer, could you please accept it? Also, if you'd like help with a different query, could you please post it as a new question, and add a comment here linking to that question?